# Energy yield of a meteor blast - how to explain the discrepancy?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, meteors

The energy yield of the Chelyabinsk meteor blast is [estimated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chelyabinsk_meteor) to be about 500 kT TNT, or $2\cdot 10^{15}$ joules. When compared that to its estimated speed ($\sim 2\cdot 10^4$ m/s) and mass ($1.3\cdot 10^7$ kg), we see that this is about all of the kinetic energy is had upon entering the atmosphere.

As far as I understand, the mechanism of the blast is that kinetic energy quickly turns into heat. This means that every kg of the meteor would receive $2\cdot10^8$ joules. Dividing by a specific heat capacity, say, of $2\cdot 10^3$ J/(kg*K), this means that the meteor would be heated to $10^5$ K. This looks unreasonable, as is seems that something dramatic must happen at much smaller temperatures (e. g., the entire meteor would vaporize, as melting and vaporization only requires $\sim 10^6$ J/kg).

So, what is going on here? Could it be that 500 kT figure refers to the entire energy, and the energy yield of the blast is much smaller? Then, how come the blast produced the shock wave capable of breaking windows a dozens of kilometers away? Does part of the shock wave come directly from the meteor going through atmospehre?

Comment: Well, the question to ask is where *else* all the kinetic energy went?  Either it went into making the meteorite & the air around it extremely hot or, well, where did it go?  Presumably the answer is that that is indeed where it went, and the abrupt conversion of (the great bulk of) the meteorite to very hot gas, together with adiabatic & frictional heating of the atmosphere around it is what the blast was.

Comment: @tfb That looks like it's closer to an answer than a comment

Comment: @tfb, it could be that at the moment vaporization starts, the meteorite explodes to small scattered fragments, most of energy still being the kinetic energy of those. They then burn in the atmosphere like normal small meteors, without major explosion.

Comment: @DavidZ: well, it almost is, but I'm hoping someone else has a more coherent model of why it all happens suddenly.  My guess is that the thing gets confined somehow by pressure, both from very hot atmosphere but also from the its own outer layers turning into gas, but I can't find any references to papers about this sort of thing: people must make models I assume.  So I'm not quite comfortable it's an answer without that.  Perhaps I could claim that, if it dumped that much energy in (say) 30s, that's an explosive event by definition.

Comment: @Kostya_I, You are assuming that all of the energy went into heating the meteor. The bulk of the energy went into the atmosphere, as heat, sound, and kinetic energy. A sizable portion (perhaps a fifth) of the energy went into light; the explosion was thirty times brighter than the Sun to nearby people. And some of the energy went into the heating and disintegration of the meteor itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am hoping that someone who understands the behaviour of meteors quantitively can give a better answer than this rather hand-waving one.

First of all, energy is conserved so the kinetic energy of the meteor as it enters the atmosphere is going to go *somewhere*.  The only question is how fast the energy gets turned into heat, really.  And I think there turn out to be only two options once the meteor has made it intact into the lower atmosphere:

1. it could survive mostly intact until it hits the surface, dumping its energy at the surface in an extremely short period of time, which will result in a significantly explosive event;
2. it could dump its energy, rather rapidly, in the atmosphere, which is also an explosive event as it will heat the atmosphere dramatically and also turn most or all of itself to very hot gas.  This is what happened to the Chelyabinsk meteor, of course.

The reason I think these are the only two options is by considering a third one and showing that it turns into the second one.  The third proposed option is that it breaks up in the atmosphere and dumps its energy relatively gradually, as the fragments slow down, get hot and 'burn up'.  Consider what happens in this case: the meteorite fragments (relatively gently) into a number of smaller objects, But these smaller objects have a significantly greater surface/volume ratio than the original meteorite since they are smaller, and they are travelling at hugely supersonic speeds in the lower atmosphere as it was, since they carry essentially all its kinetic energy.  So they are going to lose kinetic energy (and heat themselves and the air they are travelling through) *much more rapidly* than the original object.  If they themselves fragment, then their yet smaller fragments will heat *still more rapidly* as their surface/volume is still larger.  So if the object fragments in the lower atmosphere the fragments will, extremely quickly, get turned into meteor-vapour and will dramatically heat the air they pass through in the process.  This is an explosive event, almost by definition.

So this third option in fact isn't an option: it's the same as the second one, and my guess is that it's how the second one happens.  See [this SE answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/76055/165461) which describes this phenomenon rather better and has references (I wasn't aware of it when writing this answer).

So I think the only way the thing can *not* lose all its KE in an essentially explosive way is if it fragments very high in the atmosphere, which would allow the fragments to lose KE much more slowly: once it's made it to the lower atmosphere it's either going to dump all its KE into the atmosphere explosively or it's going to hit the surface, which is a different kind of explosion.

Comment: Thanks! In fact, after I asked my question, I found an answer  [https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/76055/165461] that outlines the same runaway process, with references.

Comment: Oh, thanks, that's a nice pointer!  You could perhaps argue that this make this question a duplicate I suppose.   I'm not going to vote to close it because I think it is a bit different (I've added a pointer from my answer)

Answer (score 2):

Here’s one effect that contributes.  When air is heated, either by the shock wave, or viscosity acting on the turbulent wake of a meteor, or by soft x-rays from a nuclear blast, its pressure is initially raised.  It will then expand back to normal ambient pressure, more or less adiabatically, according to the isentropic rule $P\sim {{\rho }^{7/5}}\sim {{T}^{7/2}}$ .   But the air will still be warmer than ambient due to increased entropy, and the residual heat will slowly be lost via conduction and/or convection, without conversion into mechanical blast.